# Spring Batch With Mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have created spring batch application with mongodb, I used `MongoItemReader` and `MongoItemWriter`, my batch application is working properly, know my doubt is once I ran the batch it is processing the records properly but if I run the same batch again, it is showing `Job status as completed`, as per my knowledge for non-transnational databases like `mongodb` spring batch won't create meta tables, same like there are no meta tables created in my db also, but how the job is recognized/knows job is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading few documents I was realized basic thing, for non transactional databases `Spring-Batch` will use in memory, so once the job is completed it will keep the data in it's in-memory, if you run the batch without restarting the server it will show the `JOB` status as `COMPLETED`, if you want to run it again we should restart the server.